# How to prevent float from removing zero after point?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point

I have this:

```
a = "2.10"
print float(a)
```

Where output is:

```
2.1
```

But I need output as it is.

```
2.10
```

Comment: ummm then just `print(a)`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.2f` format for this:

```
a = "2.10"
print "%.2f" % float(a)
```

Output:

```
2.10
```

Comment: Great, but I think this remains a string, I need a floating value in my actual program.

Comment: @Suparno You'll find great explanations and examples [here](https://pyformat.info/).